# How to properly insert php variables into table cells?

Tags: php, html, function

I know this sounds a little confusing, but allow me explain further.

I have a php function that prints the top of the table including the html tags as shown here:

```
function print_table_head (){
    echo "<table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>URL Link</th>
                <th>Date Start</th>
                <th>Date End</th>
                <th>Total Budget</th>
                <th>Daily Budget</th>
                <th>Model Price</th>
                <th>Unit Rate</th>
                <th>Target Info</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Total Units</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
  }
```

I also have a function that closes the table with the html table ending tags as shown here:

```
function print_table_bottom(){
    echo "</tbody>
          </table>";
  }
```

Now, the table prints fine and dandy up to here. I get the correct table headings and every thing. But I have trouble having the table body and content to print. Here's what my main function looks like for printing the entire table including it's body and content:

```
function print_table ( $status, $model, $bid, $url, $target, $tBudget,$dBudget, $tUnits, $sMonth, $sDay, $sYear, $eMonth, $eDay, $eYear ){
    print_table_head();

    echo "<tr>
            <td><?php $url[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php $sMonth[0] / $sDay[0] / $sYear[0];  ?></td>
            <td><?php $eMonth[0]; / $eDay[0]; / $eYear[0];  ?></td>
            <td><?php $tBudget[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php $dBudget[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php $model[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php $targeting[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php $product[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php $status[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php $tUnits[0]; ?></td>
          </tr>";

    print_table_bottom();

  }
```

Every time I call "print_table" function, it will print the top of the table with it's headings. But it doesn't print the table rows/cells. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can some one clear this up for me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

NOTE= I am using foundation-5. Not sure if that matters.

Also, each of the variables used is an array (they all have 1 element in them... Yes I know, I COULD have not used an array for each variable, but I want to.)

EDIT:

As request by an commenter, I will provide the code that calls print_table:

```
<?php
    //if the length of the array "status" is 1.
    if (count($status)==1){
      print_table ( $status, $model, $bid, $url, $target, $tBudget,$dBudget, $tUnits,$sMonth,$sDay,$sYear,$eMonth, $eDay, $eYear );
    }
    // please ignore this function. 
    else

      print_table_with_multiple_rows ( $status, $model, $bid, $url, $target, $tBudget,$dBudget, $tUnits,$sMonth,$sDay,$sYear,$eMonth, $eDay, $eYear );
  ?>
```

Comment: if you're echoing a block of HTML, that's a pretty good sign you need to get some templating going on instead, and probably some object oriented coding so you can make a Table var, and then call $table->toHTML() on it. This solution is not going to scale. In fact it already failed.

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of code, please? I need an example.

Comment: @JustinWood - it just prints the table headings, thats all. No table rows/cells at all.

Comment: @user3108505 If you look at the source of the page. What does the actual HTML look like?

Comment: @JustinWood - it doesn't even print show the <tr> and </tr> tags nor the <td> and content.

Comment: Why do you want them in arrays like this? What purpose could that possibly serve?

Comment: @randak, they are arrays in a previous page. not they will either have 1 element each (which is what my posting has), or they will have more than 1 element.

Comment: Go to the basics. Delete all the functions and use a pure, simple html table. Check whether it works or not. Build a function (if you want) and put all the code in. Check if it works. Separate the code in different functions. Check if it works. Profit!

Comment: I've given you the basics to answer your question, but also a more complex solution to solve your general problem, which is structure, or lack thereof. Hope it helps. You shouldn't have arrays for all your variables, so I have suggested an alternate data structure, which you can choose to ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Simple Option

The easiest option is to just to reformat your data structure and use this code:

```
$data = // Structure: array([0] => array('url' => '', 'sMonth' => '', 'eMonth' => '', ...), [1] => array(...));
include 'templates/table.php';
```

#### templates/table.php

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>URL Link</th>
            <th>Date Start</th>
            <th>Date End</th>
            <th>Total Budget</th>
            <th>Daily Budget</th>
            <th>Model Price</th>
            <th>Unit Rate</th>
            <th>Target Info</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Total Units</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data as $row) : ?>

        <td><?php echo $row->url ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->sMonth . "/" . $row->sDay . "/" . $row->sYear; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->eMonth . "/" . $eDay . "/" . $eYear;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->tBudget; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->dBudget; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->model; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->targeting; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->product; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->status; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->tUnits; ?></td>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### The Advanced Option (Better)

This might be a bit more advanced than the rest of your code, but it is a more appropriate way to write (OO)PHP in general. However, it will probably require restructuring all of your code.

Directory structure:

```
--models
    --informationmodel.php
--controllers
    --abstractcontroller.php
    --informationcontroller.php
--templates
    --information
        --table.php
```

#### models/informationmodel.php

First, a model class. This model reflects a specific type of data - in this case, whatever kind of information you're displaying in your table. This class should not be manipulating data - it is just a class that stores the data you need.

```
class InformationModel { //Where "Information" is changed to describe this data type

    private $data;

    public function __construct($data = array()) { //pass the things as an associative array
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function setData($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

#### controllers/abstractcontroller.php

This is an abstract controller. A controller is where your application logic is stored. This should include manipulation of data, model retrieval, etc. The abstract class is used by each controller to give it access to specific functions that are common to all controllers.

```
abstract class AbstractController {

    // add more functions for all controllers here

    public function renderTemplate($template, $data) {
        include $template;
    }
}
```

#### controllers/informationcontroller.php

Here is the actual controller. Within this controller we can define actions - in this case we will be defining a table action. This means that we can call this action to render a table with the data we give it. This is useful because if we want to change the way the data is presented, it is easy to do so. We could even make it so that the data is presented in a different format than HTML if we set it up to allow you to specify this. Right now, we just have a simple action: load the data, and give it to a template.

```
require_once 'models/informationmodel.php'; // note: autoloading would be preferable

class InformationController extends AbstractController {

    public function tableAction($rawData) {

        $data = new InformationModel($rawData);

        $this->renderTemplate('templates/information/table.php', $data);
    }
}
```

#### templates/information/table.php

This is a template. This is where you define the way you want the code to be displayed. If you want to go further here, look into a templating engine such as Twig (my personal recommendation). This is purely for presentation of the data. as you'll see, I've put the template into a folder for displaying a specific type of information: a table of the datatype 'information' (or whatever you change it to). This helps you to keep your templates organized.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>URL Link</th>
            <th>Date Start</th>
            <th>Date End</th>
            <th>Total Budget</th>
            <th>Daily Budget</th>
            <th>Model Price</th>
            <th>Unit Rate</th>
            <th>Target Info</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Total Units</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data as $row) : ?>

        <td><?php echo $row->url ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->sMonth . "/" . $row->sDay . "/" . $row->sYear; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->eMonth . "/" . $eDay . "/" . $eYear;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->tBudget; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->dBudget; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->model; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->targeting; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->product; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->status; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->tUnits; ?></td>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I have changed the data structure: the data is manipulated in rows, and these rows each contain only one of each element. Using a templating engine will reduce the ugliness of the `<?php echo $row->status ?>` structure - in Twig, it looks like: `{{ row.status }}`.

Then, to actually use this code:

#### whatever page you're using

```
require_once "controllers/informationcontroller.php"; //even better: use autoloading

// $data =  get your data in here somewhere.

$info = new InformationController();
$info->tableAction($data); // prints out a table;
```

Obviously this is a lot of new information, but it is useful. If you take the time to learn Object-Oriented PHP (OOPHP), MVC, templating, and so forth, you will be a better programmer, and your code will be easier to write and maintain. Further topics: Twig, Autoloading, Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control, Namespacing, Routing

Right now, the model class isn't actually doing anything, and I haven't used dependency injection (there is a direct dependency on the model class within the controller, which is frowned upon), but the basic concepts are here. For now, you could just pass the data directly to the controller, or even directly to the template.

**Disclaimer**: I haven't tested this code. However, it will require some modification anyway. If you really want to pursue writing a website in PHP, you should consider structuring it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

ehm.. you mess php and html..

```
function print_table ( $status, $model, $bid, $url, $target, $tBudget,$dBudget, $tUnits, $sMonth, $sDay, $sYear, $eMonth, $eDay, $eYear ){
    print_table_head();

    echo "<tr>
            <td>{$url[0]}</td>
            <td>{$sMonth[0]} / {$sDay[0]} / {$sYear[0]}</td>
            <td>{$eMonth[0]} / {$eDay[0]} / {$eYear[0]}</td>
            <td>{$tBudget[0]}</td>
            <td>{$dBudget[0]}</td>
            <td>{$model[0]}</td>
            <td>{$targeting[0]}</td>
            <td>{$product[0]}</td>
            <td>{$status[0]}</td>
            <td>{$tUnits[0]}</td>
          </tr>";

    print_table_bottom();

  }
```

Comment: While this is true, it shouldn't prevent the table from generating. It would just give the wrong values in each cell.

Comment: are you sure, $status[0], $url[0], ... contains a value?

Comment: @Philipp yes, they ALL have at LEAST one value.

Answer (score 0):

I find this much more readable personally:

```
function print_table ( $status, $model, $bid, $url, $target, $tBudget,$dBudget, $tUnits, $sMonth, $sDay, $sYear, $eMonth, $eDay, $eYear ){
    print_table_head();
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?= array_shift($url); ?></td>
        <td><?= array_shift($sMonth), "/", array_shift($sDay), "/", array_shift($sYear); ?></td>
        <td><?= array_shift($eMonth), "/", array_shift($eDay), "/", array_shift($eYear); ?></td>
        <td><?= array_shift($tBudget); ?></td>
        <td><?= array_shift($dBudget); ?></td>
        <td><?= array_shift($model); ?></td>
        <td><?= array_shift($targeting); ?></td>
        <td><?= array_shift($product); ?></td>
        <td><?= array_shift($status); ?></td>
        <td><?= array_shift($tUnits); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    print_table_bottom();

  }
```

Note: If it doesn't work, it might be because your PHP doesn't accept `<?=`. Substitude all the `<?=` for `<?php echo` instead in that case.

Comment: I agree, except for the short tags. This is not enabled in every environment.

Comment: I was going to put the whole thing, but since from PHP 5.4 it's enabled and in most environments is also enabled, I decided to put it. I'll write a disclaimer however.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia sorry, still no go.